# SQL Server 2000 stored procedure branching with parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a stored procedure.  If the parameter is -1 then there should not be a where clause on that column else there should be a WHERE clause.  What's the best way to do it without a lot of IF branching?

I checked the archive.  There are a few similar questions but not exactly the same.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE report
(
  @site int,
  @promo int,
  @type int
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

-- I want to avoid this:
IF @site = -1 AND @promo = -1 and @type = -1
BEGIN
  SELECT * from table
END
IF @site > -1 AND @promo = -1 and @type = -1
BEGIN
  SELECT * from table WHERE site = @site;
END
... -- other cases


ELSE  -- all parameters are > -1
BEGIN
  SELECT * from table 
  WHERE site = @site AND promo = @promo AND type = @type
END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works in many cases, (despite what the comments will say without trying it) because the optimiser will ignore the ISNULL bit. Only works for non-null columns

```
SELECT @site = NULLIF(@site, -1) ...

SELECT * from table  
  WHERE site = ISNULL(@site, site) ..
```

Otherwise, conditional WHERE which is usually bad because OR can not be optimised

```
SELECT * from table  
  WHERE (@site = -1 OR site = @site) AND  (...
```

Or separate stored procedures (don't think you want that either)

Or use sp_executesql (avoids dynamic SQL)

Comment: +1 for the NULLIF/ISNULL trick, and for being quicker on the draw with a better answer.

Comment: I implemented the first solution.  It took 4 seconds to run.  The second solution with the same parameters took 2:40 minutes.  Table has 30 millions rows.

Comment: @Yada: I have another convert! People assume it won't scale too

Comment: thanks for this gem.  I'll keep this in my sql snippet arsenal.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE
  ((site = @site) OR (@site = -1)) AND
  ((promo = @promo) OR (@promo = -1)) AND
  ((type = @type) OR (@type = -1))
```

One caveat, though, you may find that SQL is not very intelligent in optimizing this sort of query.

Answer (score 1):

why fight against the obvious, simplest solution?

seriously, the branching solution make the intent clear, and can easily be understood by others.

Comment: Works better on SQL Server 2005 though with statement level recompilation

Comment: For each column there are 2 choices. so 2^3 = 8  branching.