# In SQL, how do I allow for nulls in the parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, null

I have what seems to be a really easy SQL query I can't figure out and its driving me nuts. This is SQL 2008. Basically, there is a status field where the can pick  "pending", "satisfied" or all. If they send in "pending" or "satisfied" there's no problem. But when they pick all I'm having problems. Mostly because I can't figure out how to get the records where this field is null to show up (because it has to be 'is null' instead of '= null'. (This is the way the data will come over; I have no control over that.)

The code I've been using does not work for nulls.

SELECT     *
FROM      Payment_Table
where Payment.Status_code = @status_id

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to achieve here. Is a @status_id value of NULL supposed to mean "all statuses"? Or is it supposed to match rows where Payment.Status_code is null?

Comment: Select * is a BAD thing to do in every case.

Answer (score 6):

You can try

```
SELECT Col1, Col2,...,Coln --Required Columns
FROM Payment_Table 
where (Payment.Status_code = @status_id OR @status_id IS NULL)
```

Comment: I don't know if this will work.  It will return all rows if @status_id is null instead of just the rows where Payment.Status_code is null.

Comment: @RandomBen and that is what he / she wants.  You either select the rows with a pending / satisfied value for instance Payment.Status_Code='Satisfied' OR you select ALL the records, whether they are pending or satisfied.  In that case, this is correct it says @StatusID = NULL which in this case is true as True OR False = True.

Comment: Aggreed on the never SELECT *, just didnt see any fields specified for the select.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Payment_Table 
WHERE Payment.Status_code = ISNULL(@status_id, Status_code)
```

This will return all payments.

Comment: If there are any rows in the table where Payment.Status_Code is null, your query will not return that data.  This code should only be used if there is a NOT NULL constraint on the column.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
WHERE
    ((@status_id IS NULL) OR (Payment.Status_code = @status_id))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE Payment_Table.Status = ISNULL(@StatusID, Payment_Table.Status)
```

It usually [works better then OR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750883/sql-server-2000-stored-procedure-branching-with-parameters/1750910#1750910)

Edit: you want to select rows where Payment_Table.Status = NULL when @StatusID = NULL!!

```
SELECT * FROM Payment_Table where Payment.Status_code = @status_id
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Payment_Table where Payment.Status_code IS NULL AND @StatusID IS NULL
```

OR

```
...
WHERE
    Payment_Table.Status @StatusID
    OR
    (Payment.Status_code IS NULL AND @StatusID IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use coalesce or IsNull on your Payment.StatusCode field, this will allow you to do a substitution for null with a specific value.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Payment_Table 
WHERE (Payment.Status_code is null or Payment.Status_code = @status_id)
```

Comment: You are aware that this will include NULL Status_code even if a @status_id of other than NULL is provided?

Comment: I think the poster meant Payment.Status_Code = @status_id OR @Status_id IS NULL otherwise it is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches depending which version of sql server you are using. This articles has an in-depth description: [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

Answer (score -1):

The best way to do this is below.  However, you MUST watch out for parameter sniffing.  This will become an issue as your table gets bigger and will affect your execution times randomly.  This is an annoying issue that can pop up.  Use the code below.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetPaymentStatus
@StatusID varchar(50)=NULL
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @StatusId_local varchar(50)
SET @StatusID_local = @StatusId

SELECT MyField1, MyField2
FROM Payment_Table
WHERE Payment_Table.Status=@StatusID_local 
    OR (@StatusID_local IS NULL AND Payment_Table.Status IS NULL)
END
```

Check out this [article](http://elegantcode.com/2008/05/17/sql-parameter-sniffing-and-what-to-do-about-it/) or google sql parameter sniffing for more info.

Comment: No point in redeclaring that variable.  Also in most cases this is not a web app / security question...also this procedure was already posted by me 43 mins ago.

Comment: There is a point in re-declaring the variable.  I am pretty sure that a parameter sniffing issue could arise.  I have seen this happen before where an or statement is used where the second part of the OR clause is checking if a variable is set to NULL.  It is a minor bug in SQL Server.  What happens is SQL will scan the entire table looking for all cases where Payment_Table.Status=NULL, which we know won't return any results.  If you declare the variable locally, you force SQL to check the part of the OR Clause that doesn't involve the table.  See my link above.

Comment: That is not true, because you are not asking for payment_table.status=null you are asking for payment_table.status = @SomeVal where @SomeVal is either pending or assigned, no mention of null so the db engine does not bother doing any searching on that.